# AsyncStorage works only when app is reloaded

Tags: javascript, react-native

i set my values in Async storage while logging

```
fetch('http://xxxxx/xxxx/getUserDetails.php', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Accept': 'application/json',
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                user_id: this.state.userEmail,
                            })
                        })
                            .then((response) => response.json())
                            .then((responseJson) => {
                                const name = responseJson[0]['name'];
                                const profilePicture = responseJson[0]['profile_picture'];
                                const userId = responseJson[0]['id'];
                                const loginMode = responseJson[0]['login_mode'];
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('active', 'true');
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('userEmail', this.state.userEmail);
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('name', name);
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('profilePicture', profilePicture);
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('userID', userId);
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('loginMode', loginMode)
                                setTimeout(async () => {
                                    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
                                    this.props.navigation.navigate('userScreen');
                                }, 500)
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.log(error);
                            })
                    }
```

and delete those while logging out.

```
fetch('https://xxxxxx/xxxx/userLogout.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: userEmail
            })
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then(async (responseJson) => {
                try {
                    const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
                    await AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys);
                    this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
                    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('loginScreen');
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("Error clearing app data");
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
```

but again if i login with new user the old user details is shown in login page. if i reload my app the new values stored in async storage is shown why this is happen and this is not happening?

I am using the AsyncStorage here.

```
async componentDidMount() {
        const userEmail = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userEmail');
        const name = await AsyncStorage.getItem('name');
        const profilePicture = await AsyncStorage.getItem('profilePicture');
        const userID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userID');
        this.getWish();
        this.getAddFunction();
        this.setState({ userEmail })
        this.getResumeVideo(userEmail);
        this.getDemoVideo();
        this.getClass();
        this.setState({
            userEmail,
            name,
            profilePicture,
            userID
        })
        this.getNotificationCount(userID);
        Orientation.lockToPortrait();
        this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            this.getAddFunction();
            this.getDemoVideo();
            this.getResumeVideo(this.state.userEmail);
            this.getClass();
            this.getNotificationCount(userID);
        });
    }
```

Comment: You might want to show the code where you are writing into AsyncStorage. Otherwise, we cannot tell what's wrong.

Comment: i have edited the question, please do the needfull

Comment: yes it is javaScript @Abra

Comment: where the component you using `AsyncStorage` data? probably there you should use `useEffect` or equal, and maybe you don't assign new state or props and therefore not telling react it should render again

Comment: @HagaiHarari I have added where i use the asyncstorage

Answer (score 0):

The only place you are calling `setState` and tells react it should assign new value to state (and render...) it at `componentDidMount`, therefore React don't know it should render again.

When assigning new value to `AsyncStorage` you might also call `setState`

```
fetch('http://xxxxx/xxxx/getUserDetails.php', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Accept': 'application/json',
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                user_id: this.state.userEmail,
                            })
                        })
                            .then((response) => response.json())
                            .then((responseJson) => {
                                const name = responseJson[0]['name'];
                                const profilePicture = responseJson[0]['profile_picture'];
                                const userId = responseJson[0]['id'];
                                const loginMode = responseJson[0]['login_mode'];
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('active', 'true');
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('userEmail', this.state.userEmail);
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('name', name);
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('profilePicture', profilePicture);
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('userID', userId);
                                AsyncStorage.setItem('loginMode', loginMode)
                                setTimeout(async () => {
                                    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
                                    this.props.navigation.navigate('userScreen');
                                }, 500)

                             // here
                               this.setState({
                                 name,
                                 profilePicture,
                                 userID
                              })
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.log(error);
                            })
                    }
```

Comment: i am using  `Asyncstorage.setitem`   in separate page that is login page, and getting this value using `getItem` in userpage does this setstate works for this workflow alos?

Comment: You might create another function that will hold `setState` and pass it as to the second component or something like that